# PHP - get unique strings from array

Tags: php, arrays

I am new to this place and I have a question about PHP that I can't figure out.

What I am trying to do is create an array of strings, but that's not the problem. The problem is I have no idea how to get the only string that I need.

Example code:

```
$array = [];
$array[$game] = $string;
```

I want to keep creating strings for one single game but there will but more and more strings coming in the array from different games. I want to get only the ones from a single game, I don't know if you get what I'm talking about but I hope so because I'm frustrated that I can't figure out a way.

Comment: cant understand. please explain

Comment: Do you want to build array of strings for each `$game`? And then retrieve the strings for a specific `$game`?

Comment: I want to create an array with strings from different games. 1 game is gonna have at least 2 string and there will be around 5-10 games. I know how to set the string into a array for each game, but I don't know how to get only the strings from 1 game, that's my problem right now. I want to unset all the strings from a game once its filled up, but I can't figure out how to get the strings from a single game...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create sub array for each game then set strings inside

```
// checking it sub array already not exits to not overwrite it
if( isset($array[$game]) ){ 
    $array[$game] = array();
}
```

then only insert your string inside it

```
$array[$game][] = $string1; 
$array[$game][] = $string2;
...
```

as result you will have

```
array('somegame' => array(
                         0 => "some game string 1",
                         1 => "some game string 2",
                         ...
                    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I had done that before but it was a while loop that stopped it from working.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too simple.

You are already appending the strings to array by the key of game id.

```
$array = [];
$array[$game] = $string;
```

So, your array will look like:

```
array(
  1 => array('string 1', 'string 2'),
  2 => array('string 3', 'string 4'),
  3 => array('string 5', 'string 6'),
  //..... and more
)
```

Where keys 1, 2 and 3 are the game ids.

If you want to retrieve the keys in case of game ids 1 and 2:

```
$game = 1;
$gameStringsOne = $arr[$game];

$game = 2;
$gameStringsTwo = $arr[$game];
```

Comment: as i've been told, things being simple is relative

Answer (score 0):

Use multi-dimensional array like

```
$array = [];
$array[$game] = [ $string1, $string2 ];
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain what it does and add some references to it.

Answer (score 0):

[Read the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) Use a multi-dimentional array, push strings to an array and then assign that to another array, that way you can have multiple strings to a game

```
<?php
    $stringArray = array("str","str2");
    // if needed do array_push($stringArray,"str3","str4");
    array_push($gamelist['game'], $stringArray);
?>
```

get an array of strings when acessing game from `gamelist`

[read more](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)